# How to create a Pandas Dataframe from a dictionary with values into one column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Suppose `dict = {'A':{1,2,4}, 'B':{5,6}}`, How to create a Pandas Dataframe like this:

```
    Key  Value
0   'A'  {1,2,4}
1   'B'  {5,6}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
dct = {"A": {1, 2, 4}, "B": {5, 6}}

df = pd.DataFrame({"Key": dct.keys(), "Value": dct.values()})
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Key      Value
0   A  {1, 2, 4}
1   B     {5, 6}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can feed the dict to [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) and then convert the series to dataframe with [`reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html), as follows:

```
d = {'A':{1,2,4}, 'B':{5,6}}

df = pd.Series(d).rename_axis(index='Key').reset_index(name='Value')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

  Key      Value
0   A  {1, 2, 4}
1   B     {5, 6}
```